# Get hold of all applications by application name - TestStack.White .NET

Tags: .net, automation, automated-tests, windows, white-framework

I've 3-4 windows applications running under name **"WorkflowActionProcessor"** which I want to loop and simulate button clicks for each of these.
For simulating clicks I'm using [teststack.white](/questions/tagged/teststack.white) `.NET` library.

Below code gives me the details of only **one application:**

```
    TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach("WorkflowActionProcessor");
    Window window = application.GetWindow("Work Flow Action Processor", InitializeOption.NoCache);
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByText("Stop Execution");

    TestStack.White.UIItems.Button button = window.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(searchCriteria);
                button.Click();
```

But, How can I hold all the applications in an enumerable and process them.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to double check if there was any more information you needed from me to accept my answer? I am getting really close to 500 so if this answered your question I would really appreciate if you accepted it. Thank you.

Comment: this project got delayed a bit so I couldn't test ur answer.. will accept once I verify :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GetWindows](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/Application.cs#L253) function on application.

```
TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach("WorkflowActionProcessor");
Window windows = application.GetWindows();

foreach(var window in windows) {
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByText("Stop Execution");

    TestStack.White.UIItems.Button button = window.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(searchCriteria);
            button.Click();
}
```

Also just realized I think you meant you have 4 of the same application with the same name. There is no method in white to get all the applications of a specific name. To do this you would need to start the process 4 times and then attach to each one.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    FileName = "your.exe",
    Arguments = "your arguements",
};

List<TestStack.White.Application> applications = new List<TestStack.White.Application>();
for(int applicationCounter = 0, applicationCounter < 3; applicationCounter++) {
    TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.AttachOrLaunch(startInfo);
    applications.Add(application);
}

List<Window> windows = new List<Window>();
foreach(var application in applications) 
{
   windows.AddRange(application.GetWindows());
}

foreach(var window in windows) 
{
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByText("Stop Execution");

    TestStack.White.UIItems.Button button = window.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Button>(searchCriteria);
        button.Click();
}
```

I haven't run this code so there may need to be some tweeks to it but the general idea would be launch the application multiple times from the automation application so that you have a application object for each of them because attach will always attach to the first process with the name you specify.